# changing the system time format on windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, vbscript, powershell-2.0, datetime-format

Well I am looking for a method to change the default windows 7 time format for a system.
So if a system uses like 10PM or 10 AM  as default time notation, then i like to change that system to 10:00 or 22:00.

I know how to do it through the GUI, but in my case our software (C#) has to check if time notation is OK and if it is not change it by usage of 
C#, registry editing, vbscript, commanline or Powershell, or some specific .exe file
The software we wrote allready makes usage of external progs / languages (vbscript/powershell).
But the problem is so far i have not found a method to do this other then taking over a remote screen.

Perhaps someone knows how to do this ?
The same counts for time zone, and date notation.

Comment: Do not tamper with a user's configuration. If your application needs a different time format, re-format date/time values inside your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change the system time format using following code:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\International", true);
rk.SetValue("sTimeFormat", "hh:mm:ss"); // HH for 24hrs, hh for 12 hrs
```

But IMO, this would not be a good practice for an application to change the system user's settings without the consent of the user.

Comment: thanks i agree in normal environments this wouldnt be a wise thing to do, however here its needed, thanks

Comment: @user613326 if this answers your question, then please mark as answer. Otherwise give your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that shows it being done via vb.net but you would have to translate it. or you could compile this to an exe and run it from a shell. http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=152624

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the solution using the "Control Panel\International" registry key (sorry, can't comment due to not have a 50 reputation):

This doesn't appear to affect the existing process, only new processes created after changing the registry. And obviously code assuming registry values (i.e. implementation details) could break in a future version of windows.

Also the code should Dispose the RegistryKey object. It would be better written with a using block.

Regarding if you *should* do this, while it would be unlikely an *app* would want to change the time date format (maybe an app that's an improved way of setting system info), it would be very reasonable to need to do this in an automated test. It's a common bug for code to depend on the default time/date format, so setting them to non-default values, or testing code with various time/date formats could be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The property way to do this in .NET is with code such as the following:

```
CultureInfo newCultureInfo = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
newCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = shortDateFormat;
newCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = longTimeFormat;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCultureInfo;
```